# Matlab - Invalid file identifier. Error in savejson

Tags: json, matlab, file

I am new to Matlab and jsonlab. I'm trying to create a json file from Matlab (R2015a / Windows10) using JsonLab
but I keep getting the following error:

```
Error using fwrite Invalid file identifier. 
Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier.
Error in savejson (line 160)
    fwrite(fid,json,'char');
```

And the line 160 in savejson function of jsonlab is :

```
fid = fopen(filename, 'wt');
    fwrite(fid,json,'char');
```

Comment: How are you calling `savejson`?

Comment: What is jsonlab?

Comment: JSONlab is an open-source JSON/UBJSON encoder and decoder for MATLAB and Octave.
 https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33381-jsonlab--a-toolbox-to-encode-decode-json-files

Comment: @Suever i was following a tutorial : it was called like that :   savejson('',x,'data/matlabData.json');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third input to `savejson` is a file in which to save the resulting JSON data. In the example that you have provided

```
savejson('',x,'data/matlabData.json')
```

This is trying to create a file `matlabData.json` in the `data` folder. `savejson` is failing because the folder `data` does not exist and therefore the file cannot be created.

You can either create the `data` folder

```
mkdir('data')
savejson('', x, fullfile('data', 'matlabData.json'))
```

Or you can use your own filename which doesn't require that a folder exists

```
savejson('', x, 'matlabData.json')
```

Comment: The folder does exist , and i have tried  the second line and still it is not working

Comment: @ketimaBU Do you have permission to create files in the current directory?

Comment: problem solved i was running the application following this tutorial https://www.sitepoint.com/creating-a-web-app-with-matlab-and-the-mean-stack/ and that have openned the file so it was not possible to write while it was open in other side, thanks